# Symfony2 dynamically modified form ignores default value for new child

Tags: php, forms, symfony

So I want to modify a form basing on submitted data. I'm using that manual as an example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data

But also I'd like to provide a default value for the newly added input. To do so I set the data option for the newly added input:

```
$form->add('position', 'entity', array(
    'class'       => 'AcmeDemoBundle:Position',
    'empty_value' => '',
    'choices'     => $positions,
    'data'        => $sport->getDefaultPosition()
));
```

Unfortunately, if the input is added when I process POST_SUBMIT event, it's value gets overridden by the submitted  data. And as there is obviously no corresponding data in the request for this input (it was added dynamically), symfony sets it's value to null. So when I display the enhanced form to a user, it has an empty value in the corresponding field.

What is the best way to overcome this? I can change the submitted data in PRE_SUBMIT event, but that doesn't seem the right way.

Comment: Can you provide a little more info about your use case? You are trying to dynamically add a field to a form based on other data in that form? You then want to have a default value for the new field. But when you save it the field is just showing as null?

Comment: Have you tried binding the form without clearing missing fields? See this answer on how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291607/symfony2-how-to-stop-form-handlerequest-from-nulling-fields-that-dont-exist/25295370#25295370

Comment: Chausser, I'm adding a new field and then showing the enhanced version of the form to a user. And the rendered form has empty value in the new input. The use case is described in the referenced article, I've decided not to go into the details, cause I won't be able to explain it better then the original article.

Comment: Kix, that might be a solution to my problem! It has some flaws (I've expressed my considerations in a comment to the referenced answer), but at least it's worth considering. Besides, now I have better understanding why my values are being overwritten.

Maybe you should post it as an answer? If I won't get a better answer, I'll accept it.