# Symfony : how to force Form->handleRequest to null fields that don't exist in post data

Tags: php, forms, symfony, dynamic

I have the exact opposite question to [How to stop Form->handleRequest from nulling fields that don't exist in post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291607/symfony2-how-to-stop-form-handlerequest-from-nulling-fields-that-dont-exist/25295370).

I have a dynamic form that allows user to dynamically add and remove fields from the form.

The form allows the user to create a new entity or edit an entity. On creation, there is no problem. However, on edition, when I use `$form->getData();`, I can get an entity with invalid properties.

For example : I have an `Vehicle` Entity that can have the following values

- `Type` : Bicycle, Motorbike, Car
- `Fuel` : `integer`

The form will remove the "Fuel" field when we choose "Bicycle". But if before edition, the vehicle was a "Car" with `8 fuel`, then even if the form remove the field, `$form->getData();` will return an object with type `Bicycle` and `8 fuel`.

As requested, here is the FormType :

```
class VehicleType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, $fields = null, array $options) {

            foreach ($fields as $field_id => $field_value) {

                if ($field_id == 'vehicle') {
                    if ($field_value && ('car' == $field_value)) {
                        $form->add('gas');
                    } else {
                        $form->remove('gas');
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier, $options) {
                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $event->getData(), $options);
            }
        );

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier, $options) {
                $vehicle = $event->getData();

                $formModifier($event->getForm(), array(
                    'vehicle' => $vehicle->getVehicle(),
                ), $options);
            }
        );

       $builder->add('vehicle', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices'  => array(
                'bicycle' => 'bicycle',
                'car' => 'car',
            )
        ));

        $builder->add('add', SubmitType::class);
    }
}
```

The entity is nothing special :

```
class Vehicle
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="vehicle", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $vehicle;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="gas", type="smallint", nullable=true)
     */
    private $gas;


   (...)
```

And then, the controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/vehicle-add", name="vehicle_add")
 */
public function vehicleAddAction(Request $request)
{
    $vehicle = new Vehicle();

    $form = $this->createForm(VehicleType::class, $vehicle);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $vehicle = $form->getData();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->persist($vehicle);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('default/vehicle-add.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}


/**
 * @Route("/vehicle-edit", name="vehicle_edit")
 */
public function vehicleEditAction(Request $request)
{

    $vehicle = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Vehicle')->findOneBy(array('id' => 1));

    $form = $this->createForm(VehicleType::class, $vehicle);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $vehicle = $form->getData();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($vehicle);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('default/vehicle-edit.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: You should provide relevant parts of your code - FormType and perhaps Entity code as well. Might help people here better figure out what might be the issue

Comment: The opposite to the referenced question is exactly the default behavior. So you shouldn't need do anything to achieve it.

Comment: @DarraghEnright I just posted some parts of my code, as requested.

Comment: You already use FormEvents to add or remove gas field dynamically. You could add another FormEvent::POST_SUBMIT and add or remove fuel field.

Comment: @Rawburner Yes, but I am looking for a more scalable solution. We have actually +10 dynamics fields on this page. I thought there was maybe a parameter or something that coud just tell Symfony : "null fields that don't exist in POST data".

Comment: This parameter exists, look here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/direct_submit.html

Comment: @Rawburner it doesn't work. After a `$form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()), false);`, a `var_dump($form->getData());` still returns the whole object and not only the submitted fields.

Comment: The parameter needs to be true, its name is $clearMissing. Try this again.