# Edit entity part with form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have an entity (about 20/25 fields) and i want to edit it with a form.

I just want to edit (and display) few form field.

The problem is, all fields displayed are correctly update, but fields that are not rendered are update with "null" value by default.

My controller :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$LaboRequest= $em->getRepository('MyBundle:LaboRequest')->find($id);
$form = $this->createForm('MyBundle\Form\LaboRequestType', $LaboRequest);

if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    $em->persist($LaboRequest);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute(...);
}

return $this->render('...', array(
            'LaboRequest' => $LaboRequest,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
```

I only render few fields in my view, so i can understand, by default symfony use "null" for fields that are not render.

But is there a way to edit a part of an entity and not affect data of the entity with "null" value ?

Comment: Do you have form with all fields but you render only part of them? If it is a case try to use different forms or [validation groups](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291607/symfony2-how-to-stop-form-handlerequest-from-nulling-fields-that-dont-exist

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure you can do that.
But you can extend your original form and call

```
$builder->remove('xxx')
```

for each field you want to remove